# Перенаправление на личную страницу

Tags: php

После удачной авторизации нужно перенаправить посетителя на его профиль. 
Как поставить вместо USERNAME логин пользователя? 
Понимаю что нужно делать через Сессию, но как быть в случаи перенаправления?

```
header('Location: profile.php?teacher=USERNAME');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header('Location: profile.php?teacher='.$userName);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Location: profile.php?teacher=$userName');
```

Так тоже будет работать, но вариант выше более приемлем с точки зрения производительности. Также не забывайте что поле этой функции код идущий ниже будет выполнен. В зависимости от случая, нужно блокировать это например через exit(); которы ставится сразу после header

Answer (score 0):

запрашиваешь из БД данные пользователя по его сессии ну а дальше понятное дело вставляешь вместо USERNAME переменную с его логином.

Comment: Когда вставляешь переменную, то вместо логина появляется название переменной. например header('Location: profile.php?teacher=$username');